# Фоновые процессы во flutter не работают послле сборки

Tags: flutter, dart

Я пишу приложение на flutter, которое должно работать в фоновом режиме, и для решения подобной задачи решил использовать пакет flutter_background_service. В дебаг-режиме все прекрасно работает, но после сборки этого не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?